# How to pass parameter to shell script in Adonis JS?

Tags: javascript, shell, parameter-passing, child-process, adonis.js

I am trying to run a shell script from a post request, I want to pass parameter from the post request to this shell script.

```
const Helpers = use('Helpers')
const util = require('util')
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec)
const shellCommand = Helpers.appRoot('shellCommand.sh')
        
class someController {
  async generate({ request, response }) {
    let { VERSION } = request.body
      try {
           await exec(shellCommand + VERSION, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
              if (error !== null) {
                 console.log(error);
                 } else {
                   console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
                   console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
                 }
                })
            }
        catch (error) {
           console.log(error);
        }
     await response.send(JSON.stringify({ "status": 200, "message": "generate success", "version": version}))
            }
        
        }
```

This is how I tried to get the parameter in my shell command.

```
VERSION = $1
```

If I try running the service this is the result I got. It passes the parameter as addition to the file name instead. I know this isn't the correct way to pass parameter to shell script in Adonis JS, I've searched the internet but couldn't find the way to do it.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEgbB.png)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Nodejs api](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) you need to have space between the file name and the params, like `shellCommand + ' ' + VERSION`. Also explained in the docs, if you use the promisified version of exec don't provide a callback.